# How to handle adding new field / partial data update for a gRPC API?

Tags: c#, web-api, versioning, null, protobuf

Assuming we have following message that will be used to update data and it just got updated to version 2.

```proto
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1; // version 1
  bool is_valid = 2; // version 2
}
```

Now assuming we updated our apps like so:

- server : version 2
- client A : version 2
- client B : version 1

We don't have any problems with client A since it can set the proper `is_valid` value. The issue is that client B will always send a message with `is_valid` set to false. Is there any techniques such that the server won't use the `is_valid` field if it's from a version 1 client?

In a RESTful API, I could use PATCH to partially update data. That is, the JSON data will not have the `is_valid` field, so the server can choose not to change the said field.

Our server will be written in C#, not sure if that needs to be considered with this question.

Answer (score 3):

There's an important difference here between "proto2" and "proto3" syntax; you're using "proto3" syntax here (and the Google tooling *only supports* "proto3" syntax), and in "proto3", zeros are defaults and defaults are zeros; meaning: the **only** default value for a `bool` is `false`, and `false` is never sent; thus a missing value **is `false`**.

So if you're using "proto3", you'll have to invert this and make it `is_invalid`, then the implicit default of `false` will work.

In "proto2" you have a few more options here, but: Google's tooling *does not support "proto2"* on C#. There is non-Google tooling available, and I'm working on having it working nicely with gRPC in time for the .NET Core 3 release.

(technically it would work fine today as long as you're happy to write all the bindings manually)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how `is_invalid` makes a difference. If client A updates the resource with `is_invalid` to `true`. Then later, client B updates the same resource, wouldn't `is_invalid` be set to `false` again? **Assuming the resource is an entity in the database

Comment: @JanPaoloGo unknown fields have been preserved in the Google C# tooling since [v3.6.0](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.6.0) - of course, that only applies if you store it *as raw protobuf*; if you store it in an ORM (for example) and recreate the POCO with only the known fields, then yes: you'll burn that